# Most Efficient Method Of Checking Text Within Multiple Elements On Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input and upon the user hitting the enter key a new list item element is created containing the text that was in the input field.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to filter through all of the list item elements that exist to make sure there are no doubles upon the user hitting the enter key, and if this is even worth it.

**HTML**
*Just an input and an empty unordered list*

```
<input type="text">

<ul></ul>
```

**Javascript**
*on keyup, checks for the enter key, if enter is hit, takes the value, creates a new li, and appends the value to the new li element*

```
$( 'input[type=text]' ).keyup(function(e) {

    switch( e.keyCode ){

        case 13:

              var t = $( 'input[type=text]' ).val();
              var c = $( 'ul li' ).length;


          $( 'ul' ).append( '<li></li>' );

              $( "ul li:nth-child( " + c + " ) ").append( document.createTextNode( t ) );

           break;

            }           

});
```

*before a new li element is appended to the list, I need to check all of the li elements that already exist in the ul to be sure that an li with that value does not already exist.*

Comment: c is not defined in your case??

Comment: whoops, sorry it is not all of the code. let me fix that, trying to keep just the code that is relevant to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited above js fiddle (by milind)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb2nf/6/)**

used `.each` to loop and check

need to add one more case. if value blank, it should not be added. `This case added`

Answer (score 0):

use `:last` selector to append text node to newly added `li` element.

```
 $( "ul li:last").append(document.createTextNode(t));
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb2nf/1/)**

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks, I can definitely clean my code up with that, and thank you for that. How can I check to be sure that there are no duplicate elements though?

Comment: You mean while adding?? in that case you need to loop through all li elements and see any element do not have same text.